# Convert SWF file to PSD

Tags: apache-flex, flash, photoshop, psd

I'm looking for a solution to convert SWF files to PSD. Files i'm intending to export will be  flat SWF files with layout as per attached example (no video, animation or sound). The most important bit is that it can be exported at high quality.

I've researched this and not found many options, those that i have found had know issue with poor quality of the of the exported PSD file.

Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: Since you're flattening (supposedly) vector graphics to a bitmap format and you're doing so with what's rendered on screen, you're bound to have a resolution of 72 dpi at best. I guess your best bet is to export to a vector format (svg, ps, ...) and use PhotoShop's import functions to convert it to high resolution bitmaps.

Comment: Hi RIAstart, my issue is not being able to convert it to pdf. I'm not too bothered with the dpi as my intention is to replace all the images with higher resolution (300dpi) versions as part of my export process from SWF to PDF.  Question is can swf be exported to pdf.

Comment: You did say PSD in the original question. Check out [AlivePdf](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) and [PurePdf](https://github.com/sephiroth74/purePDF).

Comment: I do apologies, it was a typo, it's PSD that i would like to convert to

Comment: What have you found?  My intuition is that you'll have to figure out the PSD format--is it documented anywhere?--and manually create the file. Conceptually similar to how AlivePDF does it; except you need PSD files.